# Installed LAMP and NetBeans, what do I need to enter in Sources folder?

Tags: php, netbeans

I have installed `LAMP` and `NETBEANS` in my Linux pc.

I tried to run my *PHP project* but I am confused with the `Sources Folder`.

Please help in entering the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

**Sources Folder** is to specify where your sites resources (*like index.php, style.css and script.js*) are stored or would be stored.

You must select the folder where you have your resources or you want to store.

Read [setting up a PHP Project with NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#copyFilesFromSourcesFolder)